# Spring security: get Authenticated user in method

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to get back the current authenticated user in a service class with:

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

but it returns me a String username instead of a user object.

What should I do to have the user object?

Answer (score 0):

An example of how to get the authenticated user in Controller using `@AuthenticationPrincipal` :

```
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping
    public void getUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal User activeUser) {
        System.out.println("user name is "+activeUser.getUsername());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to inject it as a class variable instead of method parameter?

Comment: No since the User is specific to a HTTP request it has to be inject to method parameter first. But you can instanciate your own object for every request after and fill it with the User. What are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: I am saving an entry in a db and I need the id of the current authenticated user. So using getPrincipal I just get the username and not the entire user object. I would to retrieve the user object and from it get the id

Comment: So you just have to pass the User object to your DAO class to save it then. But it first has to be inject from a Controller's method since the data come from a HTTP request